# Why are points and vectors illustrated differently?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

In linear algebra a vector space $(V,+,\cdot)$ is [defined by the usual axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) and an element of the set $V$ is called a vector. Of particular interest in school is the three dimensional real vector space $(\mathbb{R}^3,+,\cdot)$. This space is usually visualized by a three dimensional space and its elements, the vectors, are usually visualized by arrows pointing from the origin $0$ to its coordinates. Using the definition above, a vector, that is, an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is given by a $3$-tuple $(x,y,z)$ where $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$. However, a point is usually defined to be an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as well. This means that the usual definition of "point in $(\mathbb{R}^3,+,\cdot)$" coincides with the definition of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The usual illustrations of this vector space usually distinguish between points, drawn as points, and vectors, drawn as arrows as described above.

**Question:** $(1)$ Why is this distinction in the illustrations justified using the abstract definition provided above?

I know that technically speaking $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $(\mathbb{R}^3,+,\cdot)$ are different objects, but elements of their respective sets are the same objects. So if one were to define points to be elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$ they would still coincide with vectors as elements of $(\mathbb{R}^3,+,\cdot)$. So again, I am unsure why a distinction in terminology and in illustration is justified.

**Question:** $(2)$ So using this definition are points and vectors of $(\mathbb{R}^3,+,\cdot)$ the same thing formally? Why is there a special notation for vectors if that is the case? The operations $+$ and $\cdot$ are functions and so in particular defined for elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The distinction between points and vectors is common however. As an example one can regard the problem of calculating the distance between a "point" and a $2$-dimensional subspace of $(\mathbb{R}^3,+,\cdot)$.

If one wanted to make a distinction between the two concepts mathematically, one could perhaps define vectors to be triples $(v,+,\cdot)$ where $v$ is an element of $V$ and $+,\cdot$ are the operations on $V$. This would certainly give mathematically different concepts of points and vectors, but this is artificial to me. This would however lead to the question why vectors and points can be draw in the same space, namely the three dimensional space, since they belong to different sets.

Comment: Diagrams that use arrows or dots are using them as visual aids to make a problem or its solution clearer. For example, we can ask for the normal vector at a point on a surface in $\mathbb R^3$. In this case $\mathbb R^3$ is still a vector space but in the context of this problem, it is the space in which the surface exists. The normal vector we compute is not a point in the euclidean space in which the surface exists. It is a geometric object that is represented by an arrow drawn with its base at a point on the surface.

Comment: "three dimensional plane" ?

Comment: Diagrams that show vectors originating from points are often dealing with vector fields, where a vector is assigned to each point in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the distinction between the Cartesian product $\mathbb R^3$ and the Hilbert space $\mathbb R^3$ often *isn't* drawn due to the natural embedding of one into the other.  Whether the elements are referred to as points or vectors then depends on whether we care about the vector space structure of $\mathbb R^3$ for this application.

Comment: If you're adding them together, they're vectors, not points. Because it can be very useful to consider the vector from some base point (usually called the origin) to your point, people will often automatically use that to work with a point, so I can understand why the two concepts get confused.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the main definition you need to help you make sense of things.

An **affine space** is a triple $(A,V,+)$, where $A$ is a set (whose elements are called points), $V$ is a vector space (whose elements are called vectors) and $+\colon A\times V\to A$ is an operation satisfying

(i) $p+0=p$ for every $p\in A$

(ii) $p+(v+w) = (p+v)+w$ for every $p\in A$ and $v,w\in V$

(iii) for any $q,p \in A$ there is a unique $v\in V$ such that $q = p+v$; such $v$ is denoted by $q-p$.

If you know group theory, the above conditions say that there is a free and transitive right action of $V$ on $A$. In particular, the map $+\colon A\times V\to V$ is a different operation from $+\colon V\times V \to V$.

You can add two vectors to get a vector, and you can add a point and a vector to get a point. You cannot add two points, but you can subtract two points to get a vector.

So $A$ is like a vector space who forgot where its zero is, in the following sense: whenever $o\in A$ is fixed, we have a bijection $\varphi_o\colon V\to A$, given by $\varphi_o(v) = o+v$. Defining $$p+q = \varphi_o(\varphi_o^{-1}(p) + \varphi_o^{-1}(q))$$turns $A$ into a vector space, and choosing a different $o'\in A$, we get another vector space structure on $A$, isomorphic to the first.

The thing is that when you take $A=V=\Bbb R^n$ as sets, there is a natural choice of origin $o\in \Bbb R^n$, the origin $(0,\ldots, 0)$, so the affine and vector space structures get conflated.

You can read more about it on Michele Audin's *Geometry* (this is probably the most modern reference I know for the subject).

Note: the "non-abelian" version, for an arbitrary group $G$, is a $G$-torsor: a set $X$ equipped with a free and transitive $G$-action (so $X$ is a like a group who forgot where its identity is).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am still a bit confused as to why it is justified to illustrate the same object, namely an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a point in one case and as an arrow in the other. It does not really make sense to me. Of course, we dont know what this element "is" but if we interpret it by being a point in the case of an affine space, interpreting it to then be an arrow at the same time feels hand-wavy. They shouldn't be different things, since a vector space only gives a function on the points and thus only gives extra information on what we can do with these points.

Comment: Also it still feels a bit artificial that we can conflate both diagrams. I guess one would draw $A$ and $V$ in one diagram each instead of conflating them, since they are different objects. Of course this is not done in the usual texts which feels a bit weird to me, but I think I can accept that more easily than the problem in the first comment.

Answer (score 2):

The distinction between points and vectors only makes sense in the context of an affine space. You can view an affine space as a triple $(A,V,+)$, where $A$ is a set whose elements are called points, $V$ is a vector space whose elements are called vectors and $+$ is a translation operation satisfying certain properties that ties them together. Note that $A$ is a generic set, so it does not have operations per se: that's why you can't sum two points.

$V$ can be anything you want as long as $+$ makes sense, but we usually choose the vector space that makes the most sense for our goal. For example, in the affine space $\mathbb{R}^3$, it just happens that usually $A=V=\mathbb{R}^3$. We do the same for affine subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

For example, consider the following line in $\mathbb{R}^3$:

$$r:\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{aligned} 
  z &= x+1\\
  y &= x
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation}$$

Let's call $A$ the solution set of $r$. Clearly, it misses the point $(0,0,0)$, and if you add component-wise two points of $A$, the resulting point lies outside of $r$, so $A$ is not a vector space.

If we were to turn $A$ into an affine space, usually we would get $V$ from the following line:

$$\overline{r}:\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{aligned} 
  z &= x\\
  y &= x
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation}$$

Note that we got $\overline{r}$ from simply stripping $r$ of any constant term. If we call $V$ the solution set of $\overline{r}$, $V$ is obviously a vector space.

Now let's define a translation operation $+$ that ties $A$ and $V$ together:
$$+: (x,y,z) + (\overline{x}, \overline{y}, \overline{z}) = (x+\overline{x}, y+\overline{y}, z+\overline{z}), \ \forall \ (x,y,z) \in A, (\overline{x}, \overline{y}, \overline{z}) \in V$$

$(A,V,+)$ is therefore an affine space. Note that $+$ is a nice component-wise addition, and the result is still a point of $A$. It just happened that $A$ and $V$ are both subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$, so points and vectors happened have the same "nature". If $P \in A$ and $v \in V$, when we do $P + v$ we are effectively translating $P$ along $v$. Intuitively, a translation has a direction, that is why we would draw $v$ as an arrow.

But we could choose anything as $V$, really. For example, let's say $\overline{V} = \mathbb{R}$. Then we can define:

$$\overline{+}: (x,y,z) \overline{+} u = (x+u, y+u, z+u), \ \forall \ (x,y,z) \in A, u \in \mathbb{R}$$

$(A, \overline{V}, \overline{+})$ is also an affine space. If we do:

$$(0,0,1) \overline{+} 1 = (1,1,2),$$

we are effectively translating the point $(0,0,1)$ of "one unit" along the line $r$. Translations can go two ways: one verse if $u \geq 0$, the opposite verse if $u < 0$. We would draw $u$ on the real line, with an arrow pointing to the verse of the translation.

As you can see from the last example, points and vectors can be of a wildly different nature and be drawn in completely different ways. Sometimes it just happens that $A$ and $V$ are subsets of the same set, because quite often that's just the most useful thing to do, thus they can share some similarities in their structure, but they still remain fundamentally different objects.